# View using TEMP table in postgresql also not visible outside session

Tags: postgresql

I am  creating temp table in postgresql, and there are views which are using temp table , strangely those are also not visible outside of session ,
is there any way to view to be visible to outside session and also is there any way temp table is also visible to outside of session

Comment: No, see the manual: Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or optionally at the end of the current transaction

Comment: thanks , i still could not get anything about the impact on views which are using temp table .

Comment: Your VIEW will be dropped as well, you can't select data from a table that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view on a temporary table is automatically a temporary view:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tab (x integer);

CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM tab;
NOTICE:  view "v" will be a temporary view
```

Temporary views behave like temporary tables: they will be gone as soon as the session ends, and they are only accessible from the session that created them.

You will never be able to give another session access to data in a temporary table. Whatever the problem is you are trying to solve, this cannot be the solution.

Comment: thanks a lot , this clears my doubt .